# Get clicked link, display product in another page

Tags: php, mysql

I populate a product catalog from mysql in a php while loop..
I am trying to make it so that when i click on a product that products information is displayed on another page. So far im trying to use sessions, but it always sends the last product regardless of which one is clicked. I need help!!

the catalog.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
$data = $row['image'];
$file = substr($data, strpos($data, "/") + 1);
echo "<a href='products.php'>",
"<div class='productdiv'>",
"<div class='productimage'>",
"<img class='resizedimage' src='$file' alt='{$row['name']} Image' />",
"</div>",
"<div class='productname'>{$row['name']}</div>",
"<div class='brand'>Brand -> {$row['brand']}</div>",
"<div class='brand'>Code ->{$row['code']}</div>",
"<div class='productprice'>&pound{$row['price']}</div>",
"</div>",
"</a>";
$_SESSION['name']=$row['name'];
$_SESSION['brand']=$row['brand'];
$_SESSION['code']=$row['code'];
$_SESSION['image']=$file;
}
```

And this is where i want to display it on the other page

```
echo "<div class='productcontainer'>",
"<div class='productpageimage'>",
"<img src='{$_SESSION['image']}' alt='{$_SESSION['name']}' />",
"</div>",
"<div class='productpagename'>",
$_SESSION['name'],
"</div>",
"<div class='productpagebrand'>",
$_SESSION['brand'],
"</div>",
"<div class='productpagecode'>",
$_SESSION['code'],
"</div>",
"</div>";
?>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the `$_SESSION` values every time you iterate through the array, so it's only going to "keep" the final iteration's values. If you want to set the session values in that way, you'll need to pass an identifier for your product record and then set the `$_SESSION` values afterwards (i.e. on your products.php page).  There are lots of different ways to do this - you could encode the info into the link that you've created:

```
echo "<a href='products.php?name=" . $row['name'] . "&brand=" . $row['brand'] . "&code=" . $row['code'] . "&'>"
```

Then set the $_SESSION using the values from $_GET on the products.php page:

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $_GET['name'];
// ... etc.
```

Or, more commonly, pass just the identifier (do you have a product ID?) and then perform another sql lookup on products.php.

Comment: how do i pass the product id?

Comment: Do you have a product id in your product table? (What fields make up your `product` record?) What you're looking for is the field that uniquely identifies the product. (Is the 'name' field unique?) If you could post your table schema and the query you're using, that would be helpful.

Comment: suppose you have to pass hello on other page then use, www.something.com/?anything=hello and on the other page use $_GET['anything'] to get values from url.

Comment: Thank you guys, i got there in the end!